# Align navigation item with dropdown having icon in BootstrapVue

Tags: bootstrap-vue

When I place an icon into `b-nav-item-dropdown` the vertical alignment of navigation bar gets broken:

[image]
[image: tr]

```
<b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">
  <b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'sign-in'}">Sign in</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item-dropdown toggle-class="text-warning" right>
          <template v-slot:button-content>
            <b-icon-info font-scale="2"></b-icon-info>
          </template>
          <b-dropdown-item :to="{ name: 'help'}">Help</b-dropdown-item>
        </b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

How can I align them? Is there BootstrapVue native way? The nav components miss `align-v` attribute.

Comment: Solution: <b-icon-info scale="2"></b-icon-info>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `font-scale` (which increases the font size of the icon), use the `scale` prop, which uses a CSS transform to increase the icon size without changing the font size (as mentioned by @Hiws on Discord channel).

```html
          <template v-slot:button-content>
            <b-icon-info scale="2"></b-icon-info>
          </template>
```